# Struggling to get multiple async calls to work using DispatchGroups

Tags: swift, xcode, api

My table view is not populating after the async (api) calls finish. The second async call inside of the for loop needs the first async call to be done before executing (it is dependent on it since it uses the movie array from it). I can't seem to figure out the proper way to make this work and get my variables to persist from the async calls to pass on to my tableview after exeting `DispatchQueue.main.async`.
Here is my code:

```
    let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()
    
    DispatchQueue.main.async
    {
        dispatchGroup.enter()
        GenresMDB.genre_movies(genreId: categoryNum[genre], include_adult_movies: true, language: "en") //first async call
        { [weak self] apiReturn, movieList in
            
            guard let self = self else {return}
                   
            if let movies = movieList
            {
                for movie in movies
                {
                    self.movies.append(MovieDT(title: movie.title ?? "Missing Title", description: movie.overview ?? " ", releaseDate: movie.release_date ?? " ", stars: movie.vote_average ?? 0, id: movie.id ?? 0))
                }
            }
                
            dispatchGroup.leave()
                
            for movie in self.movies
            {
                dispatchGroup.enter()
                self.db.collection("Movies").document(String(movie.id)).getDocument() //second async call (multiple calls) -> this needs the first async call above to be finished
                { [weak self] (querySnapshot, err) in
                    guard self == self else {return}
                    if let err = err {
                        print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
                                    }
                    else
                    {
                        guard let snap = querySnapshot else {return}
                        let data = snap.data()
                        self!.upvoteCount.append((data?["upvoteCount"] as? Int ?? 0) - (data?["downvoteCount"] as? Int ?? 0))
                    }
                    dispatchGroup.leave()
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    dispatchGroup.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main) {
        print("Async calls finished")
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

Comment: @Sh_Khan Everything populates properly inside of the `DispatchQueue.main.async` but once exiting it all variables are empty

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work like those though I don't think this is the proper way to do it.

```
let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup() 
    DispatchQueue.main.async
    {
        dispatchGroup.enter()
        GenresMDB.genre_movies(genreId: categoryNum[genre], include_adult_movies: true, language: "en") //first async call
        { [weak self] apiReturn, movieList in
            
            guard let self = self else {return}
                   
            if let movies = movieList
            {
                for movie in movies
                {
                    self.movies.append(MovieDT(title: movie.title ?? "Missing Title", description: movie.overview ?? " ", releaseDate: movie.release_date ?? " ", stars: movie.vote_average ?? 0, id: movie.id ?? 0))
                }
            }
                
            dispatchGroup.leave()
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        
            for movie in self.movies
            {
                dispatchGroup.enter()
                self.db.collection("Movies").document(String(movie.id)).getDocument() //second async call (multiple calls) -> this needs the first async call above to be finished
                { [weak self] (querySnapshot, err) in
                    guard self == self else {return}
                    if let err = err {
                        print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
                                    }
                    else
                    {
                        guard let snap = querySnapshot else {return}
                        let data = snap.data()
                        self!.upvoteCount.append((data?["upvoteCount"] as? Int ?? 0) - (data?["downvoteCount"] as? Int ?? 0))
                        print((data?["upvoteCount"] as? Int ?? 0) - (data?["downvoteCount"] as? Int ?? 0))
                    }
                    dispatchGroup.leave()
                    self!.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            }
        } //why does it have to end it all the way here for it to work?
    }
    
    dispatchGroup.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main) {
        print("Async calls finished")
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
```